# Maximal space and Zorn's lemma

Tags: general-topology

Let be $(X, \tau)$ a Hausdorff space without isolated points. I want to prove that for the order relation $\subseteq$, every order subset of $A =\left\{\tau_x: \tau_x  \text{ is a topology on } X, \ \tau_x\supseteq\tau, (X,\tau_x) \text{ doesn't have isolated points} \right\}$ has an upper bound in $A$.

Comment: Let $C$ be a chain in $A$. Have you considered trying to show that $\bigcup C\in A$?

Comment: Yes, it was the first I thought.

Comment: What part of it is giving you trouble?

Comment: I could not proved that the union of elements of the order chain is a topology on X.

Comment: Okay: that’s reasonable, because it might not be. It’s almost what you need, though. Let me write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a chain in $A$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup C$. If $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{B}$, then there is a $\tau_i\in C$ such that $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\tau_i$, so $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\in\tau_i\subseteq\mathscr{B}$. Thus, $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology

$$\tau_{\mathscr{B}}=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}$$

in $A$. This topology clearly contains $\tau$. Since no member of $C$ contains a singleton $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$, $\mathscr{B}$ also contains no singleton, and adding the unions cannot add a singleton, so $\tau_{\mathscr{B}}\in A$, as desired.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the help. Can you explain me why there exist $ \tau_i \ \in{} \ C$ that contains the finite subset.

Comment: @dajc: You're welcome. It's because each $F\in\mathscr{F}$ belongs to some $\tau_F\in C$, and $C$ is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$, so one of these topologies $\tau_F$ contains the others; take it as $\tau_i$. It's just using the fact that every finite subset of a linearly ordered set has a maximum element.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** The increasing union of topologies might not be a topology, but it generates a unique topology. In order to see that it will not have any isolated points, show that if the topology generated by the increasing union of these topologies had an isolated point $\{x\}$, then $\{x\}$ was open in one of the topologies in the chain.